# Операционка на жестком диске подключенном к ноутбуку через переходник usb-sata

Tags: usb, windows-8

Всем привет, у меня испортился старый ноутбук, я извлек из него жесткий диск с windows 8. Недавно приобрел переходник sata-usb и попытался загрузиться с этого жесткого диска на новом ноутбуке. Однако в итоге получаю сообщение об ошмбке "the device is installed is locked", я пытался его восстановить, как было предложено во многих статьях, ничего не помогло. Вставил этот жесткий диск вместо дисковода на пк и windows запустилась, потому первый вопрос: почему операционка не запускается через usb, провод исправен, мне получалось открыть содержимое диска через него? Отсюда вытекает второй вопрос, если я разобью жесткий диск с нового ноутбука на два логических и на один из них перекину содержимое локального диска C старого диска, что-то из этого выгорит? И вообще, что можно предпринять, чтобы windows таки заработала на жестком диске через usb. Жалко просто, много програм было установлено на ней, их придется восстанавливать очень долго, а так как у меня сейчас линукс, то и не все получится нормально восстановить, заранее спасибо

Comment: Как я помню у винды такое не поддерживается или может быть https://uk.pcmag.com/operating-systems-and-platforms/88253/feature/how-to-run-windows-10-from-a-usb-drive

Comment: @Hellseher я так понимаю это ддя windows 10?